# browserify multiple or single entry points

Tags: amd, browserify

I'm trying to use browserify to concatenate all my JS dependencies and JS sources and I understand I can use two methods I can use.

**Method 1**

**browserify.js**

```
entries: './single-entry.js'
```

**./single-entry.js**

```
require('./vendor/1');
require('./vendor/2');
require('./vendor/3');
```

---

**Method 2**

**browserify.js**

```
entries: ['./vendor/1', './vendor/2', './vendor/3']
```

Which method should I be using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not be getting a response because without know more about the structure of your project, no one can know which method is more appropriate.

If your project has multiple entry points, use method 2. If it has one entry point, use method 1.